# What does "OEM strings" mean in dmidecode output?

Tags: linux, dmidecode

When I run the command `sudo dmidecode`, **OEM Strings** entries change everyday. Yesterday, they were like the following:

```
OEM Strings
String 1: 2WYGio4ByI3fS
String 2: Mqd4eRO2YezsP
String 3: 3N0poAdRciCcs
```

Now, they are like the following:

```
OEM Strings
String 1: VNJq-77fKzTx+
String 2: h+8cgFuyKXP-o
String 3: 2l25nHrRCEgKb
```

What does "OEM strings" mean in dmidecode output?

Comment: OEM strings information can be patchy with dmidecode as it relies on information being supplied by vendors. If they haven't changed any hardware, the information should be the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OEM Strings are free-form information stored in the System Management BIOS (see the [spec](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf) for details). The values themselves don’t matter (much), however you wouldn’t expect them to change when fans are cleaned.

There is probably a simple explanation though: part of the service process might involve updating the firmware to the latest version, which could change the OEM Strings; or perhaps the technicians replaced the motherboard (which happens quite often during laptop servicing).